# Trouble uploading large file with PHP and HTML Forms

Tags: php, html, upload, localhost

So I'm trying to make some for a university project, and I've got the website set up as local host. I'm trying to upload a video file and a csv file together. Below is the code for the HTML form:

```
<form action="scripts/addVideoScript.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000000000000"  type="hidden"/>
        <input type="file" accept=".mp4" name="video" /><br>
        <input type="file" accept=".csv" name="csvFile" /><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

And here is the php script in scripts/addVideoScript.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

$targetDirectory = '../videos/raw/';

$video = $_FILES['video'];
$csvFile = $_FILES['csvFile'];

$text = "";

if (move_uploaded_file($video['tmp_name'], $targetDirectory . $video['name'])) {
    $text = $text . $video['name'] . " has been uploaded. ";
} else {
    $text = $text . $video['name'] . " did not upload. ";
}
if (move_uploaded_file($csvFile['tmp_name'], $targetDirectory .$csvFile['name'])) {
    $text = $text . $csvFile['name'] . " has been uploaded.";
} else {
    $text = $text . $csvFile['name'] . " did not upload.";
}

echo '<script>
        alert("'. $text . '");
        window.location.href = "../addVideo.php";
      </script>';?>
```

When I change the accept tag for the form, and try to upload 2 other files, it does actually work. The problem seems to be with the video file. I went in the php.ini file and changed the upload_max_filesize to 4G, because I thought it was a file size problem, but that didn't fix it. If it helps, the video is about 400MB in size.

Also when doing the upload with the video and other file, neither of them upload, so it could be a problem with my HTML form, but I can't see where.

What am I doing wrong? Is it something stupid?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *"I went in the php.ini file and changed the upload_max_filesize to 4G, because I thought it was a file size problem, but that didn't fix it."* - Did you do a restart?

Comment: was `post_max_size` changed?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner yes I did.

Comment: @OlegButuzov No it wasn't, but that fixed it. Thank you very much.

Comment: `ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '1024M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '1024M');` why did you remove that from your original post?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I realised I'd copy and pasted the old .php file that I was using, not the new one

Comment: well, I can't see why you accepted that answer, given that's exactly what you had in your original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case `upload_max_filesize` setting isn't enough, also need to fix `post_max_size`.

Comment: You rock. Completely forgot about that!